# http redirect to specific https link

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a webpage that I would like to redirect to a specific link if the user is coming from http://

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var loc = window.location.href+'';
    if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0){
      window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://secure.example.com/app');
    }
</script>
```

If the user comes from http://example.com/app or any http:// I would like to redirect it to that exact link.

When I run this JavaScript it is taking https://secure.example.com/app and adding domain.com/app like below

> https://secure.example.com/appexample.com/app

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried the meta tag thing 
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=https://secure.example.com/app" />`

But its just keeps refreshing and doesnt feel right with the hesitation page change.

Comment: This seems too arbitrary. What if the url is something like `http://mysub.domain.com`? Should that be changed into `https://secure.domain.com` or `https://secure.mysub.domain.com`? The rules here don't seem well defined on when to replace a subdomain with `secure` vs when to append `secure` to the original domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var loc = window.location.href+'';
    if (loc.indexOf('http://www.')==0){
         window.location.href = loc.replace('http://www.','https://secure.');
    }
    else if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0) {
        window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://secure.');
    }
</script>
```

It was doing what you describe because you were replacing `http://` with `https://secure.example.com/app` so of course everything that was after `http://` will still be there afterwards.

Comment: Ok, I'll change the answer

Comment: www.example.com/app and example.com/app needs to turn into secure.example.com/app

Comment: There you go, you could have done it with a regex but this is more straightforward.

Comment: how would you do it with a regex? If youre bored hahaha

Comment: @DavidBrierton you would use a pattern like `http:\/\/(www\.){0,1}(example\.com)` if it matches then you need to change to https and you use the second 'group' in your replace like `https://secure.\2`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simply replacing `http://` with `https://secure.` when there's no `www`.
To additionally cover cases where there **is** a `www`, you can simply replace `www.` with nothing:

```js
//var loc = window.location.href;
var loc = 'http://www.example.com/app';
console.log(loc);
loc = loc.replace('www.', '');
loc = loc.replace('http://', 'https://secure.');
console.log(loc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your server configuration file instead of doing it in html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

301 REDIRECT should be the better way to do it

for an javascript approach(es6). not the recommended way because browser redirect is not always reliable

```
 return location.protocol != 'https:' ? location.protocol = "https:" 
: {do nothing logic}
```

Comment: but its only one page